# how to get container ID & IP from then ansible yaml?

Tags: docker, ansible

Is there a better way to get the IP & container ID while using ansible to download & start services?

I don't know the id neither the IP before it starts... so I get theses information from register variables...

Currently I'm based on that method:

```
  - name: start docker service 
    service: 
      name: docker1
      state: started
  - name: load and start the container we wanna use 
    docker_container:
      name: test
      image: rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd
      state: started
      ports:
       - "49154:22"
  - name : get container ID
    shell: docker ps | grep -i ubuntu-sshd | awk '{print $1}'
    register : container_ID
  - name : get container IP
    shell: docker inspect --format '{''{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }''}' container_ID
    register : container_IP
  - name: Wait maximum of 300 seconds for ports to be available 
    wait_for:
      host: 0.0.0.0
      port: 49154
      state: started
  - name: force docker to accept sshkey
    shell: sshpass -p root scp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@container_IP:/tmp/
```

Is this really the good way to do ?
if not how can I do that ? (get IP  & ID to run modules to the container after this steps)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code in the question works. It should be posted to [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) per [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow/211790#211790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name:` you pass to the `docker_container:` block can be used to address the container for all purposes; you never need the hex container ID.

The container-internal IP address is essentially useless, and I’d remove the block that looks it up.  Since you publish port 49154 on the host, you can access the service via `{{ ansible_hostname }}:49154`.

Comment: ok Thanks, I'm doing it well as soon as I call the service with variable {{ ansible_hostname }}:49154...